# Java- Draw only in certain areas

Tags: java, graphics

I am trying to draw circles (representing people) on a PNG map of Earth. Obviously, I don't want people to be floating in the oceans as the simulated civilization expands. How would I create specified areas on the map that I can draw on? Can I simply restrict the background of the PNG?

I tried using the clip() method, but it still allowed spawning within the oceans. Any suggestions (or if you recommend clip(), how would you use it in this case) would be appreciated.

Comment: If the color is blue where the circle is to go then don't draw there.

Comment: You're not explaining the context here. What library are you using? What is `clip()` being called on, what arguments does it take, and in what class is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

You somehow have to tell your program where drawing is allowed and where not. There are a bunch of approaches to this:

- Try to define a set of features on your PNG image and only spawn (or don't spawn) civilizations if these features are met.
- Make a "map" out of your map. Define areas on your PNG image where spawning is allowed and where spawning is not allowed. You can use this using the `Polygon` class for example.
- Make a second PNG image in which you make all oceans purely transparent. Then, only spawn civilizations on the original image at locations where the image with transparency is non-transparent.

Just a bunch of ideas.